# I want to fill a combobox with a database field

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I have a little problem with my code. I want to fill a combobox with a database field:

```
     const string connMysql = "DataSource=localhost; Database=ph; Uid=root; Pwd=;";
            myConn = new MySqlConnection(connMysql);
            string cad = "SELECT answers FROM `questions` WHERE (`test_num` = '1')";
            myConn.Close();
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand = new MySqlCommand(cad, myConn);
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();            
            if (myReader.Read())
            {
                CB1.Items.Clear();
                CB1.Items.Add(myReader[0].ToString());
}
```

I use this and in `combobox` just keep 1 field and I want to fill with all content of "answers".

Comment: Your code is created to actually only keep 1 field. `if (myReader.Read())` should read only once I think, and you're clearing the combo box and adding first value only. What you can do is using `while(myReader.Read())` (Not tested) and inside you keep adding your values. You will need a counter for that ofcourse.

Comment: Does your query return any rows?

Comment: If you want everything in the combobox maybe dont add `myReader[0]` just once... Loop over the collection/data bind it. how to do this is all over the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers this is what I do:

```
        const string connMysql = "DataSource=localhost; Database=ph; Uid=root; Pwd=;";
        myConn = new MySqlConnection(connMysql);
        string cad = "SELECT answers FROM `questions` WHERE (`test_num` = '1');";
        myConn.Close();
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand = new MySqlCommand(cad, myConn);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        CB1.Items.Clear();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            CB1.Items.Add(myReader[0].ToString());
            }
```

The `combobox` fill with all content of "answers"

Comment: if your question was answered you should select the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

As others stated, you're only adding the one field,  iterating over the query works.

```
 const string connMysql = "DataSource=localhost; Database=ph; Uid=root; Pwd=;";
        myConn = new MySqlConnection(connMysql);
        string cad = "SELECT answers FROM `questions` WHERE (`test_num` = '1')";
        myConn.Close();
        myConn.Open();
        myCommand = new MySqlCommand(cad, myConn);
        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();     
        int i = 0;
        CB1.Items.Clear(); //Clear the Combo box once before adding values
        while(myReader.Read())
        {
            CB1.Items.Add(myReader[i].ToString());
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Your code will keep clearing the ComboBox and only last field will be found.